# How to read file or stream until string found

Tags: c++, stream, out-of-memory

I am writing a dictionary program, the input is specified by a file and parsed as such:

```
std::string savedDictionary(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifstream(DICTIONARY_SAVE_FILE)), {});
// entire file loaded into savedDictionary
for (size_t end = 0; ;)
{
    size_t term = savedDictionary.find("|TERM|", end);
    size_t definition = savedDictionary.find("|DEFINITION|", term);
    if ((end = savedDictionary.find("|END|", definition)) == std::string::npos) break;
    // store term and definition here...
}
```

This throws `std::bad_alloc` on some of my third world users' machines that don't have enough RAM to store the dictionary string + the dictionary as it's held inside my program.
If I could do this:

```
std::string term;
for (std::ifstream file(DICTIONARY_SAVE_FILE); file; std::getline(file, term, "|END|")
{
    // same as above
}
```

then it would be great, but `std::getline` doesn't support a string as delimiter.
So, what's the most idiomatic way to read the file until I find `"|END|"` without allocating a crap ton of memory up front?

Comment: unclear why you think you need to allocate a "crap ton of memory". You have to keep at most 5 characters in memory to find `"|END|"`

Comment: the stream apis seem to force you to read until a specific character is found, or specifiy that character as EOF to read through the entire stream. i don't have one specific character that i can read until to be sure i have reached `"|END|"` and reading the entire stream is a crap ton of memory

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to read data from a `istream`. What does the actual dictionary file look like? There is likely to be a better way to parse it than one `char` at a time via `std::istreambuf_iterator`

Comment: no they dont. eg `get` lets you read any number of characters you like

Comment: It looks like `|TERM|bonjour|TERM|hola|TERM|こんにちは|DEFINITION|hello|END||TERM|Adios|DEFINITION|bye|END|`.

Comment: Oh, didn't see `get` had an overload like that x_x. Probably gonna use that, though I'll leave it open if anyone has a better way.

Comment: I didnt want to answer in comments, just tried to find out if it was  false premise that led you to the code you have or if there were some requirements you missed to mention.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file CSV".  Your example is reading fields using the `|` as a separator. Same technique for CSV file, except the delimiter is different.

Comment: The terms and definitions might have `|` in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in the future, this is what I ended up writing:

```cpp
std::optional<std::string> ReadEntry(std::istream& stream)
{
    for (struct { char ch; int matched; std::string entry; } i{}; stream.get(i.ch); i.entry.push_back(i.ch))
        if (i.ch == "|END|"[i.matched++]);
        else if (i.matched == sizeof("|END|")) return i.entry;
        else i.matched = 0;
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the requested functionality by using a very simple proxy class. With that it is easy to use all `std::algorithm`s and all `std::iterator`s as usual.

So, we define a smal proxy class called `LineUntilEnd`. This can be used in conjunction with all `stream`s like a `std::ifstream` or whatever you like. You can especially simply use the extractor operator to extract a value from the input stream and put it into the desired variable.

```
    // Here we will store the lines until |END|
    LineUntilEnd lue;

    // Simply read the line until |END| 
    while (testInput >> lue)    {
```

It works as expected.

An if we have such a string, we can parse it afterwords with easy regex operations.

I added a small example and put the resulting value in a `std::multimap` to build a demo dictionary.

Please see the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>


// Ultra simple proxy class to read data until given word is found
struct LineUntilEnd
{
    // Overload the extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, LineUntilEnd& lue);

    // Intermediate storage for result
    std::string data{};
};

// Read stream until "|END|" symbol has been found
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, LineUntilEnd& lue)
{
    // Clear destination string
    lue.data.clear();

    // We will count, how many bytes of the search string have been matched
    size_t matchCounter{ 0U };

    // Read characters from stream
    char c{'\0'};
    while (is.get(c))
    {
        // Add character to resulting string
        lue.data += c;
        // CHeck for a match. All characters must be matched
        if (c == "|END|"[matchCounter]) {
            // Check next matching character
            ++matchCounter;
            // If there is a match for all characters in the searchstring
            if (matchCounter >= (sizeof "|END|" -1)) {
                // The stop reading
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Not all charcters could be matched. Start from the begining
            matchCounter = 0U;
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// Input Test Data
std::istringstream testInput{ "|TERM|bonjour|TERM|hola|TERM|hi|DEFINITION|hello|END||TERM|Adios|TERM|Ciao|DEFINITION|bye|END|" };

// Regex defintions. Used to build up a dictionary
std::regex reTerm(R"(\|TERM\|(\w+))");
std::regex reDefinition(R"(\|DEFINITION\|(\w+)\|END\|)");

// Test code
int main() 
{
    // We will store the found values in a dictionay
    std::multimap<std::string, std::string> dictionary{};

    // Here we will store the lines until |END|
    LineUntilEnd lue;

    // Simply read the line until |END| 
    while (testInput >> lue)    {

        // Search for the defintion string
        std::smatch sm{};
        if (std::regex_search(lue.data, sm, reDefinition)) {

            // Definition string found
            // Iterate over all terms
            std::sregex_token_iterator tokenIter(lue.data.begin(), lue.data.end(), reTerm, 1);
            while (tokenIter != std::sregex_token_iterator()) {

                // STore values in dictionary
                dictionary.insert({ sm[1],*tokenIter++ });
            }
        }
    }

    // And show some result to the user
    for (const auto& d : dictionary) {
        std::cout << d.first << " --> " << d.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```